# My Basic Angular App failing me when i'm designing my First Mean stack UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, declaration, mean, angularjs-module

```js
app.js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    myApp.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope){    
        $scope.name="vignesh";
       
    });
```

I'm doing a basic app building with MEAN Stack, for most of the parts we use Node API's to connect with MongoDB and user authentication,I'm done with my authentication part in Node.js but while designing routing UI I'm facing this issue

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <title>User Story</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.16/angular-route.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">{{name}}</div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/service/authService.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

```js
angular.module('authService',[])

  .factory('Auth',function($http,$q,AuthToken){

   var authFactory={};

   authFactory.login=function(username,password){
    return $http.post('/app/login',{

     username:username,
     password:password

    }). sucess(function(data){
     AuthToken.setToken(data.token);
     return data;
    })
   }
   
   authFactory.logout=function(){
    AuthToken.setToken();

   }


authFactory.isLoggedin=function(){
 if(AuthToken.getToken())
  return true;
 else
  return false;
}

authFactory.getUser=function(){
 if(AuthToken.getToken())
  return $http.get('/api/me');
 else
  return $q.reject({message:"user has no token set"});

}
return authFactory;

  })

  . factory('AuthToken', function($window){

   var authTokenFactory={};

   authTokenFactory.getToken=function(){
    return $window.localStorage.getItem('token');

   }

   authTokenFactory.setToken=function(token){
    if(token)
     $window.localStorage.setItem('token',token);
    else
     $window.localStorage.removeeItem('token');
   }
return authTokenFactory;
  })

  .factory('AuthInterceptor',function($q,$location,AuthToken){

   var interceptorFactory={};
interceptorFactory.request=function(config){
 var token=AuthToken.getToken();
 if(token){
  config.header['x-access-token']=token;
 }
 return config;
};
interceptorFactory.responseError=function(response){

if(response.status==403)
 $location.path('/login');

return $q.reject(response);
}

  })
```

```js
controllers.js
angular.module('mainCtrl', [])

   .controller('MainController', function($rootScope,$location,Auth){
    
    var vm = this;
    vm.loggedIn = Auth.isLogged();
    $rootScope.$on('$routechangeStart',function () {
     vm.loggedIn=Auth.isLogged();

     Auth.getUser().then(function(data){
      vm.user=data.data;
     });

   });

vm.doLogin= function(){
             
             vm.processing=true;
             vm.error='';
             Auth.login(vm.loginData.username, vm.loginData.password)
                 .sucess(function (data) {
                  // body...
                  vm.user=data.data;
                 });

                 if(data.success)
                  $location.path('/');
                 else
                  vm.erroe=data.message;
             }

   
     vm.doLogout=function(){
      Auth.logout();
      $location.path('/logout');
     }


   })
```

error says:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
>
> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   myApp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not
>   available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
>   If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as
>   the second argument.

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize you app module correctly.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0hHQSI7sspgnfdUSXKzA?p=preview)

**Update**

As you have different module per each JS file, you need to combine them while using any provider/service that module, As in your case you have used `Auth` service but the `authService` module has not injected.

**Controllers.js**

```
angular.module('mainCtrl', ['authService']) //injected authService module

   .controller('MainController', function($rootScope,$location,Auth){
```

**App.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['mainCtrl']);

    myApp.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope){
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. i tried that solution, still same issue

Comment: **here is the full error from chrome console:**

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
controllers.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
app.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
angular.js:4154 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp

Comment: If i remove ng-app's value it working fine for entries like:{{4+7}}

Comment: load app.js before the `authService.js`

Comment: @VickyR Take a look at updated answer.. could you add your `authService.js`, `controllers.js` & `app.js` code in your question..

Comment: added mate.. yeah I've successfully tried running html as separate file   but when i initiate through a nodejs server i'm facing this issue. I'm trying a simple thingonly though lot more to do with routes